# How to design InfoHelper for html title attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

For Asp.net mvc core app:
In one of my dbcontext tables I have records with HelpInfo (id as primary key, and string for helpInfo) that I want to use as html title attributes in my razor views, such as:

`<div title='@I(12)'></div>`

Where 12 is an example id of a HelpInfo record and @I should be a global accessible class method that fetches the corresponding helpInfo string.

I tried to implement King Kings approach such as:

**The CustomView**:

```
public abstract class CustomView<TModel>  : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    protected IInfo Info => Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IInfo>();

    public Task<string> I(int code)
    {
        return Info.GetAsync(code);
    }
}
```

**The Interface**:

```
public interface IInfo
{
    Task<string> GetAsync(int code);
}
```

**The Service**:

```
public class Info : IInfo
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    public Info(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(int code)
    {
        var myRecord = await context.MyRecords.FindAsync(code);
        if (myRecord != null)
        {
            return myRecord.Info;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In _ViewImports.cshtml I added `@inherits CustomView<TModel>`

In the view I used `<div title='@(await I(12))'>Test</div>`

When I load the view I get

```
No service for type '...Models.IInfo' has been registered
```

Any help to pin down the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand looks like you want something like `@Html` or `@Url` which are supported in the default `Page` and `RazorPage`. That's just a custom property exposed by the base page. So in your case, you need a custom view (for mvc) or a custom page (for razor pages). Here is an example of a custom view used for MVC:

```
public abstract class CustomView<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{              
    //custom members can be declared in here
}
```

Based on your desired usage of `I`, it must be a method. So it can be a method exposed by some service injected in your base page. Suppose that interface is like this:

```
public interface IInfo {
     string Get(int code);
}
```

Now your custom page can implement the `I` method like this:

```
public abstract class CustomView<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{      
    //NOTE: the custom page class does not support constructor injection
    //So we need to get the injected services via the Context like this.
    protected IInfo Info => Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IInfo>();        
    public string I(int code){
       return Info.Get(code);
    }
}
```

To use your custom view, you need to use the directive `@inherits` in your view or better in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` so that you don't have to repeat that `@inherits` everywhere, like this:

```
@inherits CustomView<TModel>
```

Sometimes the base view is not applied (so the base members are not available) until you rebuild your project.

Now you can use the `I` in your views as what you desire, like this:

```
<div title="@I(12)"></div>
```

Note the `I` method returns a `string` in my example, you can also make it return an `IHtmlContent` (e.g: `HtmlString`) or whatever type you need for your requirement.

**NOTE**:

Technically you can use any services (including ones querying for data from database), but in such cases please ensure that the querying is as fast as possible and use `async` to have the best performance & avoid thread starvation. Here is an example of the `IInfo` service that queries from a database:

```
public interface IInfo {
     Task<string> GetAsync(int code);
}

public class Info : IInfo {
     //inject whatever your Info needs
     //here we just need some DbContext (used in EFCore)
     public Info(InfoDbContext dbContext){
        _infoDbContext = dbContext;
     }
     readonly InfoDbContext _infoDbContext;
     public async Task<string> GetAsync(int code){
         var info = await _infoDbContext....
         return info;
     }
}
```

The `I` method then should be `async` as well:

```
public Task<string> I(int code){
       return Info.GetAsync(code);
}
```

I hope that you know how to register a `DbContext` to use in your code (that's part of `EFCore` so you may have to learn more about that first). Now to use the `async` method, you call it in your view like this:

```
<div title="@(await I(12))"></div>
```

Again, I would try to avoid querying the db in such a helper like that. As I said, the helper's method can be called multiple times right in one same view so usually we have fast methods or use ***caching*** for the info it need. This is related to another feature called `caching` which has more to be put in one short answer, you can learn more about that.

Comment: I tried your approach, but I am stuck at : protected IInfo Info { get; } = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IInfo>(); where I get red squiggling under Context and the error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static, method, or property 'Razor.Page.Context'.

Comment: @Manu sorry, see the update. If `=>` is not supported in your environment, try declaring it as a public get private set (not readonly as I wrote before).

Comment: Now with: protected IInfo Info => Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IInfo>(); no errors come up. But I still need some more help, as to geting the HelpInfo into the return string. Am I correct when I fetch the HelpInfo from my dbContext inside the pubic string I(int code) method? Or else?

Comment: yes that's right, if there is something wrong, just let me know. Actually I've run a simple demo against this code (for MVC).

Comment: @Manu it's possible to inject a service to query data from the DbContext, please see my ***NOTE*** section updated in my answer, generally speaking we should avoid slow querying to ensure that the performance is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your further help. Yes I know about DbContext from EFCore and I am using it a lot. I will dive into your suggestions given in your NOTE section. You are correct, I will have to study for a while in order to get it right.

Comment: @Manu yes, actually all the data you need (especially business data) should be fetched into the view model. That's the strict rule of MVC. But we loose it a bit by supporting data source from right in the page/view class (including the support for DI). That may be convenient in some cases but anyway the data access should be fast, we can control what we load into the view model easily but not for the others scattered through the view.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

To my Startup.cs I added:

`services.AddScoped<IInfo, Info>();`

`services.AddTransient<IInfo, Info>();` also does work.