# How can pass a data context to a static method in Asp .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to pass ApplicationContext to a static method. I tried many different ways, but nothing worked.
I tried it without statics and much more, the context always returns null.

This is the original code I wrote, but it gives the errors "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property"

```
public class SelectItemHelper
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext db;

    public SelectItemHelper(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDeveloper()
    {
        var developer = db.Games.ToList();

        IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var dev in developer)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = dev.Article, Value = dev.Article });
        }    
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access instance members from a static method !

Comment: I understand. Maybe there is some other way?

If I make it not static, then how can I call it razor page?
If I create an instance of a class, then I will need to add an empty constructor. And it still returns null

Comment: you can put it in a service and ***inject*** it in your page/view or integrate it as part of your custom page, recently I've answered a similar question here (about custom view) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428656/how-to-design-infohelper-for-html-title-attribute/66431179#66431179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the `static` keyword, hence making the method an instance member
- Register your class as a service in the **ConfigureServices**:
  `services.AddScoped<SelectItemHelper>();`.

Thus, you can simply inject your class: in a controller or a view (using `@inject`)